# Closing an Inner Function

Tags: python-2.7, function

This may be a simple question but I wonder wether an inner function which is defined within an outer function as in the example below, closes, when the outer function is closed? Is there a way to check if the inner function is closed? Thanks for some comments.

```
def outer(x,y):
    #some varibale definitions

    def inner():
        #do something

    inner()     

    return None
```

Comment: Since you are not returning the inner function it won't be referenced by anything anymore and should also garbage collected.

Comment: What do you mean by `closed` exactly?

Comment: @Anmol Singh Jaggi  By "closed" I mean that the function doesn't still run in the backround. I'm prolly not aware but is there any other definition, or how would one define "to close" a function?